Pre-commit git hooks
My company is adopting a VDI architecture. To enhance the code security, we want to use pre-commit hooks, what I really need to do is automate the whole process in such a way that all the reposetories have these git hooks, and the developer has to do nothing but clone the project, work on it, and commit.
So I tried to work with the gitlab pipeline, but I'm still encountering the following problems :
_ the dev still have to manually run the pre-cimmit install command so as to create the pre-commit file in .git/hooks

I have to put some restrictions on some files in a way that the developers can't modify them, for example (.pre-commit-config.yaml).


There's no "automagic" way that ensures git hooks are installed as desired and there's no way to prevent devs from locally modifying the commit hook scripts. The consequence of those two facts is that pre commit hooks on the client should only ever be used for convenience: verify some condition that should be holding true, but don't depend on it. If you need reliable checks, you need to do them on the server-side where devs can't manipulate them.

It's not an exact duplicate, but this question has very relevant answers.

is there a way i can use a docker image

There's no way to make this work: anyone who has the credentials to check out the git repository will be able to do that in as "passive" a way as they desire: you provide data, you can't force them to execute any given part of that data (unless you have some outside control over their devices, but even then it's an uphill battle). I don't see how "a docker image" would change that.
